# Specific Benefits of Using Date Column Type in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

What are the pros/cons to using the Date field in Marketing Cloud opposed to just leaving it a text field?  Will comparisons work the same? Will there be issues down the road if it is a text field and not date?

Thank you!

Comment: No experience with Marketing Cloud, but dates tend to be stored in databases in a standard format (like ISO 8601) that computers know how to use date math on and can easily be represented to an end user in their own locale and format. If you use a text field, what is stopping someone from entering any of these problematic values? "February 30th, 2021", "20/2/3", "Last Friday"

Comment: Here is a good explanation (its based on SQL tables, but that is basically what a DE is): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759012/when-to-use-varchar-and-date-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One benefit is, you can do comparisons like DateAdd().
- You can also insert auto-generated values for "current date".
- You can at any time reformat data in date fields using built in functions in SQL and AMPScript (e.g. FormatDate)
- None of this works for text, and there are possibly more things that elude me now.

==

- The main downside is, marketing cloud will store them in a format pretty unuseable for other systems
- gotcha: marketing cloud system timestamps are servertime, which is UTC-6.

My personal practice is:

I use date fields for everything "internal", whenever data needs to be used in emails, restructured, compared... ALL OF THIS IN SERVERTIME, I never store localTimes here, so that the SFMC-internal comparisons work consistently.

I *never* use date fields when the data extension is going to be exported.

In this case, I create a second DE with text fields only. Then I purposefully reformat the date to varchar (text), specifying the desired format and making sure I add 6 hours (to offset the servertime to UTC difference).  In the second DE, I explicitly mention the converted timezone (now UTC) in the fieldname, such as "myDateUTC". This second DE serves as "exportReady" data for only this purpose.

example:

```
SELECT
Dateadd(hh,6,convert(varchar,someDateInServertime,104)) AS myDateUTC
FROM
myDEWithDates
/* overwrite myExportReadyDEWithText */
```

list of some useful formats:
https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

That way, I get all the benefits where needed, but have none of the downsides.

Comment: I have almost never run into issues with exporting the date fields from SFMC to an external system, can you give me some examples of the issues you run into as that is concerning to me that you have so much trouble with it. Also, do not forget that storing a date as a varchar datatype will use more storage space and at high volume can increase processing times when accessing it. Also, sorting on 'string dates' is a complete mess. Lastly too - it is easy to accidently store a non-date value into the string which when later trying to convert can blow up your process.

Comment: Any external system that requires Dates as, say, format  "2021-11-14" in a flat csv file, which happens to us almost in any project. Absolutely agree on storage and access. Like I say - These "export" data extensions are not used for anything else but exporting, say a daily raw data set to ftp. No sorting, no calculations, no integrations to anything.

Comment: I have not come across a time when the exported dates were specifically required to have to be exactly `YYYY-MM-DD` or it would fail - interesting and definitely something to consider though.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Jonas Lamberty is right in some areas, I had to put up another answer as I disagree with other parts and want to share in case it helps someone else:

---

**[reference for this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759012/when-to-use-varchar-and-date-datetime)**

### VARCHAR INSTEAD OF DATE:

- You can't easily add / subtract days to the VARCHAR version.
- It is harder to extract just month / year.
- There is nothing stopping you putting non-date data in the VARCHAR column in the database.
- The VARCHAR version is culture specific.
- You can't easily sort the dates.
- It is difficult to change the format if you want to later.
- It is unconventional, which will make it harder for other developers to understand.
- In many environments, using VARCHAR will use more storage space. This may not matter for small amounts of data, but in commercial environments with millions of rows of data this might well make a big difference.

---

**[SFMC DE Datatypes documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5)**

### OFFICIAL DE DATATYPE:

- A system date
- Use an AMPscript function to format
- Date attributes are accepted in various formats, such as 1/1/2005 or January 1, 2005
- All dates are stored as MM/DD/YYYY, and dates entered in a different format are updated when stored
- Date values generated by the Marketing Cloud use Central Standard Time unless documented otherwise
- Valid date values are 01/01/1753 to 12/31/9999
- You can add a HH:MM time value following the date value, such as 12/12/2012 12:12 PM.

---

I have also found (quite the opposite experience of Jonas) that it transfers quite a bit better as a Date format than it does as a String, most especially as you would need to do multiple formatting and debugging/massaging on your String dates to make sure it is a real date and won't blow up your import by having a datatype mismatch.

As you can see the dates are stored in `MM/DD/YYYY` which, in most cases, is an easily understood date format. Albeit, the default for SQL is `yyyy-mm-dd` so its not the same exact 'universal' format, but with this prior knowledge you should be able to easily make any shifts or alterations on ingestion to allow for easy import.

Comment: Thank you - I remember I had some problems in the past with date comparisons in MC with differing column types.  Appreciate your follow-up here on the flip side.